# How to find the back-EMF constant of BLDC motor from a motor technical data?

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, torque, back-emf

I have a BLDC motor with these info (please don't pay attention to the striped column):
[image]

How from these info, how can I get the Back-emf constant ? Is it just 36V/4krpm = 9 V/krpm ?

Thank you a lot.

Comment: Welcome! Likely less than 36 V at 4000 rpm, but there is not enough data to know. The inverter will also obfuscate it to a high degree. What do you need the back-EMF constant for?

Comment: @winny Thank you. I'm using ST Motor Control Workbench for a project and I need to set some parameters such as the ones you can see on the picture. The last parameter to set is the back-EMF constant and I don't know what to put in. The default parameter is 4.0 Vrms/kprm

Comment: The inverter inside it will again obfuscate it for you. If the motor has a PWM or speed control input, you don't need any motor driver for it since it already contains a motor driver.

Comment: For brushless DC motors Kemf = Kt.

Answer (score 1):

For an ideal synchronous AC motor (including so-called "brushless DC motors"), the voltage constant is equal to the torque constant. Real motors, of course, are not ideal, but this is still a good enough approximation for most uses.

So for this one, the voltage constant is 0.063 N·m/A = 0.063 V·s = 6.6 V/krpm.